# Authentication to Google Chat API for deployed function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, bearer-token

I wrote a Google Cloud Function, which sends a message, to a Google Chat using Webhook. The script is working fine and the messages are arriving while testing the function. If I deploy the function I get the error message: "**Your client does not have permission to get URL /post-error from this server."**
My reffering service-account has already the role: Cloud-Functions-Invoker

How to change settings or script to give the client acces, without allowing not-authorized requests?

- I distributed the role Cloud-Functions-Invoker to the service-account
- I deployed the function allowing not-authenticated requests. Then everything is working. But I dont't want to do this, since I work in a business context.
- I called the function with authentication-data in my header, then everything is working as well:
  curl  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" 
  https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME